# Giving an iOS 8 custom keyboard internet access

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8

I want to give my IOS 8 custom keyboard access to the internet, so that I may load in images and ads for the user to see. Right now, nothing displays when I run my application, although all the elements are there in my interface builder. I believe that the problem that causes the ads from iAd to not be visible is because the keyboard can't access the internet. Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard cannot "access the internet" by itself. Could you please be mord specific about what you are trying to achieve? iAds are served normally even while testing; some times Apple won't return an ad so you can check your error handling logic (you can also do this by turning off internet access).

Comment: I am trying to display an iAd Banner view within an IOS 8 custom keyboard view. For example, underneath the keys to enter text, there will be a banner.

Answer (score 0):

According to App Review Guidelines, 3rd party keyboard mustn't display ads, see 25.3 paragraph:
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#extensions

As to Internet access in general, App extension points using NSURLSession is the way to go: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW2